# How do I fix this redirect error? HTTP not redirecting when called from an encrypted localhost script (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

My hardcoded script when I hit submit calls
http://127.0.0.1/?act=Arcade&do=newscore

I enforce HTTPS so in this case, it does not appear to redirect because a script is calling it.

I need this to redirect to **index.php?act=Arcade&do=newscore**

This is what I have in the .htaccess file already

```
Options All -Indexes

# Swap index.html index.php for the HTML start page

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on

# Force SSL - no insecure data connections!                                                      

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443%{REQUEST_URI}

# Force WWW - this is only needed for root domains...                                           

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Security Rewrites

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\?act\=) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (sql_login) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (basepath) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (libpath) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (absolute_path) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (vwar_root) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (includedir) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (file=http:\/\/) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (name=http:\/\/) [OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (phpbb_root_path)

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://127.0.0.1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well, just use a relative link for the redirection in the script, not a full URL.

Comment: I do not have access to the script internally as it is encrypted.

Comment: Then how can you use it, if it is "encrypted"? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: You could try to implement a substitution filter changing the response content that script generates. I remember doing that some years ago to inject a piwik snippet into each response. Apache offers the substitution module (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) which allows to implement a string based substitution. Given that you have an issue with a fixed, literal string, that should be possible.

Comment: They are flash files that have been compiled. When a game is finished it sends a redirect to add the score to a database. Hard coded is 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and in my server config it just does not work. I have multiple domains on a shared ip and cPanel changed something that is reversible but after each update I would have to edit multiple domains to keep it working.

Comment: Flash? This is 2022 ... I am out.

Comment: arkascha - do a search on GitHub for ruffle; Adobe Flash may be gone but we will take it from there. I run flash on my site with no problems. My problem was running a game someone else compiled. You do not need browser plugins to run flash on my site, I handle everything before I send it to the browser. Flash never left and the few still running Flash game sites are making money hand over foot because everyone fell for the lie. Any code can be a risk if the author is is a black hat...

Comment: The funny thing about vulnerable technologies is that you never know that you actually have a problem. The fact that no technology offers a guaranteed security is _not_ a valid reason to use technologies that have a long record for being insecure by design. No one keeps you from using this technology, I certainly won't. All I said is that I am out.